# Creating private messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faye

I'm writing a simple mini-chat with custom `User` model and authentication via `omniauth`. The chat uses web-socket `faye-rails` to send and display messages instantly without refreshing the page. The matter is that I'd like to add private messages - I mean, that I can choose an user and start our own dialog in a secondary chat window. I've looked for the solutions, but everything I found was about e-mailing - with inbox messages, trash cans and so on. So I wonder if there's any solution easy to implement.

The source code of my chat is [here](https://github.com/AlexNikolaev94/chatclone.git)

Comment: @MatthewCliatt sorry, updated

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to push technology and active web design!

When someone logs in, present them with a list of friended accounts and logged in state. For logged in friends, they can select a friend from the list and start a chat session in a new window. For logged out friends, they can send a message that's delivered the next time the recipient logs in.

You'll then have to create a friending mechanism that allows a user to request a connection to a prospective friend, be notified of pending connection requests, approve friend requests, and an unfriend feature. Hopefully that one won't be used too often.

I've worked with Faye & I like Faye but also take a quick look at the beta release of Rails 5. Action Cable will do the same thing and the framework support is better.

Comment: thank you! I've updated my repo, so the source code is present. The matter is that I have one chat window with messages in it, I also tried to make a list of users currently online but didn't succeed. I planed this as something like - you want to start a private dialog with particular user, so you click a link near his name and then the private dialog window appears

Comment: I think that's a good direction. If it were my project, I would start with a quick proof of concept. Use Rails & HTML to open a new chat window in the browser when clicking on the link. Get that working first

Once I got the plain vanilla version working, then I would progress to a private dialog popup along the lines of FaceBook chats. The pop up dialog will require Javascript and DOM manipulation in order to add something that didn't exist at the time the page was rendered to HTML.

Neither step is particularly hard but separating them might make the whole task easier.

Comment: I possibly get how can I create private message window but I completely don't get how to create the very process of private messaging - I mean, to initiate a dialog with particular user and show in that window only current user and another user messages

Comment: Your root path -- the place where the user starts -- is messages#new. In my mind, a new message adds a message to a conversation that is already going. What if your root path is to a friends#index page, where a user has a list of friends presented as a grid. Each friend row has a conversation link to take them to a list of messages between the logged in user and their friend.